# invoking an async task on fluentassertion

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

probably a simple one, but cant get it to work;

i've changed the signature one on the methods to Task

On my unit tests i am using fluent assertions.

but cant get this to work:

```
        _catalogVehicleMapper
            .Invoking(m => m.MapToCatalogVehiclesAsync(searchResult, filtersInfo, request, default(CancellationToken)))
            .Should().Throw<ArgumentException>()
            .WithMessage("One of passed arguments has null value in mapping path and can not be mapped");
```

the `MapToCatalogVehiclesAsync` is the async method, but i need to await it, but awaiting and asyncing the invocation, doesnt seem to do it..
someone..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although Fabio's answer is correct as well, you can also do this:

```
_catalogVehicleMapper
   .Awaiting(m => m.MapToCatalogVehiclesAsync(searchResult, filtersInfo, request, default(CancellationToken)))
   .Should().Throw<ArgumentException>()
   .WithMessage("One of passed arguments has null value in mapping path and can not be mapped");
```

And as a side-note, I suggest to always use wildcards in `WithMessage`. See point 10 from [this blog post](https://www.continuousimprover.com/2015/11/12-tips-to-write-unit-tests-that-dont.html).

Answer (score 4):

`Invoking<T>` extensoin method returns `Action` which with asynchronous method is equivalent to `async void` - so exceptions will not be awaited.

As workaround you can wrap method under the test to a `Func<Task>`.

```
[Fact]
public async Task ThrowException()
{
    Func<Task> run = 
        () => _catalogVehicleMapper.MapToCatalogVehiclesAsync(
            searchResult, 
            filtersInfo, 
            request, 
            default(CancellationToken));

    run.Should().Throw<ArgumentException>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This technique allowed me to keep the Arrange / Act / Assert pattern! :)